# Showing the existance of a base with certain conditions

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $V$ be a vector space and $S \subset T \subset V$, with $S$ being an linearly independent set of vectors and $T$ being a generator set of $V$.

Show that exists an base $B$ for $V$ with $S \subset B \subset T$.

My thoughts are two:

- If $S$ is a linear independent subset of $T$, with $T$ being an generator set, then $S$ is a base for some subspace $V' \subset V$. Then we can extend $S$ to be a base $B$ for $V$. But I can't think in how can I extend $S$ to have $B \subset T$ guaranteed.
- If $T=\{w_1,...,w_m\}$ generates $V$, then $m \geq n$, with $n$ being the dimension of $V$. So the vectors of $T$ can't be linearly independent, and we can eliminate some $w_i$ until we get an linearly independent subset of $T$ that generates $V$, that being the base $B$. But how can $I$ do that process ensuring that $S \subset B$? I know that $S$ is an linearly independent set, but in that process, some vectors of $S$ could be lost, right?

I can't conclude the question because of that two doubts. Any leads? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A bit late to the party, but here we go: The answer to this question depends on whether $T$ is finite or infinite. But in principle the first idea you presented already goes in the right direction.

If $T=\{w_1,\ldots,w_n\}$ is **finite**, one usually starts with
$$
B:=\begin{cases}
S&\text{if }w_1\in\operatorname{span}(S)\\
S\cup\{w_1\}&\text{else.}
\end{cases}
$$
The $j$-th step ($j=2,\ldots,n$) then consists of keeping $B$ as it is if $w_j\in\operatorname{span}(B)$, and adding $w_j$ to $B$ otherwise. After $n$ steps one is left with a set $B$ which is linearly independent, and satisfies $S\subseteq B\subseteq T$ as well as $T\subseteq\operatorname{span}(B)$. But the latter implies $V=\operatorname{span}(T)\subseteq\operatorname{span}(\operatorname{span}(B))=\operatorname{span}(B)$ meaning $B$ is a basis of $V$ as claimed.

Now if $V$ is of **infinite dimension** then this result still holds, but the proof we presented above breaks down because our selection process may not terminate as it could be infinite. This is where [Zorn's lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zorn%27s_lemma) comes into play; the argument orients itself towards the [proof that every vector space has a basis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basis_(linear_algebra)#Proof_that_every_vector_space_has_a_basis). Define
$$
P:=\{B\subseteq T:B\text{ linearly independent, }S\subseteq B\}\,.
$$
This set is non-empty ($S\in P$) and partially ordered by means of the set inclusion, hence it has a maximal element $B$, i.e. if $B'\in P$ satisfies $B\subseteq B'$ then $B$ and $B'$ have to coïncide. To show that $B$ is a basis of $V$ we have to show that $B$ is linearly independent (holds by definition of $P$) and that $\operatorname{span}(B)=V$.

Indeed assume that $\operatorname{span}(B)\subsetneq V$ so there exists $x\in V\setminus\operatorname{span}(B)$. By assumption $x\in\operatorname{span}(T)=V$ so $x=\sum_{i=1}^mc_iw_{\alpha_i}$ for some $m\in\mathbb N$, $c_i\in\mathbb K$, $w_{\alpha_i}\in T$. But this means that $w_{\alpha_i}\not\in\operatorname{span}(B)$ for some $i=1,\ldots,m$ so $B\cup\{w_{\alpha_i}\}$ is linearly independent; therefore $B\cup\{w_{\alpha_i}\}\in P$. This contradicts maximality of $B$, hence $\operatorname{span}(B)=V$ and $B$ is a basis of $V$ as claimed.